# How to add the next two consecutive numbers in a list using import sys for line in sys.stain print(line end=)

Tags: python

The for example is 1,2,3,4,5,6

And I would have to get 1,3,6,10,15,21
By adding the numbers next to each other.
I don’t know where to start any help appreciated

```
Import sys 
For line in sys.stdin print(line end=“”)
```

Comment: If you are trying to write something this simple and genuinely have no idea where to start, then it is not possible to help you here. This is not a tutoring website.

Comment: I know how to do this, but not with the starters shown with import sys

Comment: Well, what happened when you tried putting `python sys.stdin` into a search engine?

Comment: It says it means standard output and can be used to get input from the command line directly

Answer (score 0):

simple solution would be:

```
sum_cons = [1,2,3,4,5,6]
sums_res = []
curr_sum = 0
for num in sum_cons:
    curr_sum += num
    sums_res.append(curr_sum)
print(sums_res)
```

Outputs:

```
[1, 3, 6, 10, 15, 21]
```

Comment: I coded something similar to this but I’m trying to learn how to use the sys.stdin.